# Remove all Overlays

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, itemizedoverlay

I have the following code to add an Overlay

```
myMapView.getOverlays().add(sites);
myMapView.invalidate();
```

I also have the following remove code where sites is a global variable.

```
if (sites != null) {
                // myMapView.getOverlays().clear();
                myMapView.getOverlays().remove(sites);
                myMapView.invalidate();
                sites = null;
            }
```

Sometimes I am left with duplicates so would like a way to remove all overlays from a map, is this possible?

Comment: `myMapView.getOverlays().clear()` does not clear the map?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Looks like I did have the answer all along!

myMapView.getOverlays().clear()

Comment: But I cannot add overlays after clearing using .clear().